# How to delete drupal's unused core modules correctly?

Tags: php, module, drupal

I want to delete the unused drupal modules like ( blog, Forum, taxonomy ...) but I'm worried if I delete the modules from the modules directory I might cause an error (now or in the future).

Is it safe? and if I deleted the corresponding tables what will happen?

The reason for this is because I want to deliver the site to my client, and teach them how to use the admin page, but I want to make as easy as possible for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting Drupal core modules is plain wrong for many reasons, the number one is the newbie intro advice to Drupal.

> Don't hack core.

Changing Drupal core files opens up to a world of pain.

What you want is not really deleting the modules anyways. What you want is to remove them from the modules list. Though I personally think it's wrong to do it, as always with Drupal there is a way to do it, without altering Drupal itself. The solution is `hook_form_alter()`. With it you can just remove the modules fro
the modules list form. That would be the way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting modules, you can configure an user for your client limited only to those sections of the admin area you want to show.

It's a better and more general solution.

Comment: I understand your point, but lets say I want to delete a module?

Answer (score 0):

You could theoretically just delete them out of the modules directory without any immediate problems, but it's not recommended. There's no reason to, and you'd have to do it each time you updated Drupal, among other problems.

Comment: I slightly disagree with the "there's no reason to" and would rather say "You don't have a good reason to." There are places where it is appropriate, namely looking at the PHP module which allows for PHP input on the server. We want to make absolutely sure this can't be accessed so we delete it. However, hacking core is bad.

Comment: @nowarninglabel: have you ever seen the Bad Judgement Module? http://drupal.org/project/bad_judgement
there is an issue there: there is no Good Judgement module. I'd say it would be nice to have one, conflicting with PHP Filter (and doing nothing else). Thus you wouldn't need to delete PHP Filter, and your client would certainly avoid disabling Good Judgement.

Comment: @barraponto: Woudn't work for my use case, but may be good for othres. Imagine this scenario. You provide the hosting for your client, and absolutely no access to the server itself. You give your client user 1 permissions on the Drupal site. Now, the only way to prevent them being able to execute PHP is to delete the PHP filter in core. Otherwise, one would have to muck around with permissions, which is going to be quite a pain to do on every site you roll out as opposed to just have standard build without the PHP module in it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no point to deleting them. You could download a contrib module later, and it might rely on Taxonomy, Forum, Color, Upload.. etc. I would advise to leave them alone.